# What would prevent WordPress from sending emails to non-local email addresses?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, exchange-server

I have setup our blog on my local machine with **PHP5.3/FastCGI and MySQL (Windows 7/IIS 7.5)**... (FYI - I'm new to Windows Servers and IIS)

I got this message:
*The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...* when a co-worker clicked the 'lost password' link on the 'wp-login' page.

I defined our network's mail server via 'php.ini' and voila!- Lost password email worked. -or so I thought.

Turns out, emails such as the lost password and new-user (password) are only being successfully sent to users with our mail server's url address (johndoe@horsepowerfreaks.com)

**So my question is: Why would WordPress not be able to send emails to email addresses outside our domain? I know the first thing people will guess (as I have) that it is something to do with our mail server (Microsoft Exchange Server)...**

Could it be something to do with the config of WP?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a security configuration problem with your Exchange SMTP server, not with WordPress. Take a look at this:

http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2011/10/unable-to-relay-mail-to-external-domain.html

Comment: I will have to have our admin take a look at this when he can. I could see this being the solution. I'm hoping it's not anything too complicated. Thanks for the advice. All is appreciated :)

Comment: Will post if this is found to be a solution to my issue :)

Comment: Do you think this is a possibility even if our normal outlook messages are able to be sent to all different domains. We have had a functioning exchange server for quite sometime now and have never had an issue sending messages...

Comment: Exchange's security model is extensive, and I believe that by default it is very restrictive of automated messages.

Comment: Since you said you configured PHP to send messages through Exchange and messages are working in-domain, the only two possibilities are that you didn't configure php.ini properly and PHP is sending those messages some other way, OR that exchange is configured not to send messages from PHP outside of the domain. Wordpress emphatically doesn't care where it's sending email.